# Jquery calling function on hashchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, hashchange

I have 2 questions

1. I am using the hashchange plugin .... so I want to know would a function as below, be called everytime a hashchange occurs... because I have something like that in my code and the code function apparently doesnt seems to be called

   ```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
       // function here
   });
   ```
2. On the other have if I remove the hashchange as in If i make http://abc.com/a.htm#http://abc.com/b.htm  as http://abc.com/b.htm 
   the code works fine

the problem is the structure of my pages is a bit different .... here is the fiddle with the page structure that explains on a higher level what I am trying to achieve [jsfiddle.net/vBKWd/9](http://jsfiddle.net/vBKWd/9) ... on hash change jus the div c on my page 1 gets replaced by page 2 and vice versa .... and the js function that I have shown below is getting called only once and not after hashchange

Or is therre any way I can bind the function with the div so that whenever the div is replace the function get called?

Comment: your example doesn't convey anything. maybe add some more details?

Comment: can we see the code of your function?

Comment: @amosrivera the function works perfectly fine ... the problem is that it is called once when the page is loaded but not on hash change ....

Answer (score 3):

No, a `ready` handler is only called on document ready, not on hash change. You should use the `hashchange` event for that, instead:

```
$(window).hashchange(function () {
    // function here
});
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/vBKWd/2/

Comment: "didnt work"... could you be a bit more descriptive? Maybe produce a JSFiddle example of it not working? You're saying that the code in place of `// function here` is not called on `hashchange`, or does "didnt work" mean something else?

Comment: @Domenic ... is therre any way I can bind the function with the div so that whenever the div is replace the function get called?

Comment: I don't understand; are you using the comments to ask an entirely separate question? I'd suggest asking a new question for that, and marking this one as answered if it has been, or deleting it if you don't care about the answer.

Comment: @Domenic sorry for not being descriptive ... yes the //function here is not called on hash change ..... and I didn't ask another question in the comment ... the reason for asking that was that the hashchange function replaces div so if you might be aware of any function that might trigger on div change that would do the job ....  I would get right on making a fiddle for this ... anyways thanks for the effort +1

Comment: there is no as such function which triggers om div change..you can make your own using `trigger(function1())`, existing jquery function.

Comment: @Domenic the problem is the structure of my pages is a bit different .... here is the fiddle with the page structure that explains on a higher level what I am trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/vBKWd/9/ ... on hash change jus the div c on my page 1 gets replaced by page 2 and vice versa .... and the js function that I have shown below is getting called only once and not after hashchange ... does that help?

Comment: @koool sorry, that fiddle isn't very helpful at all. It displays nothing and `xyz` is undefined. And I don't understand why you have to use `ready`, when the whole point of my answer is that you should not use `ready`, you should use `hashchange` instead.

Comment: I will try and make the whole thing so that it would we working on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

In document ready wirte code below

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
                 //code here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use `live` in this case

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
   $(selector).live(hashchange, function(){
    // your code goes here

    });
});
```

Comment: the problem is the structure of my pages is a bit different .... here is the fiddle with the page structure that explains on a higher level what I am trying to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/vBKWd/9/ ... on hash change jus the div c on my page 1 gets replaced by page 2 and vice versa .... and the js function that I have shown below is getting called only once and not after hashchange ... does that help?

Comment: `ReferenceError: hashchange is undefined`. Also, `live` has no effect with applied to `"hashchange"`, and the `hashchange` event cannot be applied to non-`window` objects. -1